# iPhone application not working on iPhone 5s iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9.2

My iPhone application having checkmark functionality on `tableview`,all is working fine on iPhone 6 but Facing issue with iPhone 5s.If I select row,check mark functionality not working.I am not able to figure out the exact cause.How can I check the problem? Please help me.
here is my `UITableView`

**delegate method code:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   selectedTransIdArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:userSession.transactionArray];   
NSLog(@"selectedTransIdArray first %@",selectedTransIdArray);

NSString *state = [dataTransArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selectedTransIdArray addObject:state];
    userSession.transactionArray = selectedTransIdArray;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selectedTransIdArray removeObject:state];
    userSession.transactionArray = selectedTransIdArray;
}

NSLog(@"selectedTransIdArray %@",selectedTransIdArray);
userSession.transactionArray = selectedTransIdArray;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedTransIdArray forKey:@"aKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by checkmark functionality. Can you please post your code?

Comment: What functionality did you add? Have u added UI in storyboard or programmatically .

Comment: Are you sure your table view isn't too wide on the iPhone 5?

Answer (score 0):

u have to write a algorithm which tell u that this row data is checked or not.
and accordingly change value of checked objectatindex value

```
if (indexPath.row == checked){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition you are checking is not behaving as you expected. Checking for cell's accessory type is not working, instead can you check whether the `state` is present in `selectedTransIdArray`like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   selectedTransIdArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:userSession.transactionArray];   
NSLog(@"selectedTransIdArray first %@",selectedTransIdArray);

NSString *state = [dataTransArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(![selectedTransIdArray containsObject:state])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selectedTransIdArray addObject:state];
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selectedTransIdArray removeObject:state];
}

NSLog(@"selectedTransIdArray %@",selectedTransIdArray);
userSession.transactionArray = selectedTransIdArray;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedTransIdArray forKey:@"aKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```